# SQL Case MAX WHEN LIKE

Tags: sql, max, case, sql-like

I would like to create a case statement or a rank over statement for a particular outlier case I have.

I am not sure how to write a case statement utilizing CASE (pseudo code)

```
WHEN MAX Total_Revenue COMPANY like 'ABC%'
else COMPANY
```

i have tried rank over, but it is not working:

```
,RANK() OVER(COMPANY LIKE 'DEF%' ORDER BY  Total_Revenue DESC) AS grp
```

Current table:

```
Company    Total_Revenue
ABC        10
DEF1       25 --This row will NOT be selected as its less than
DEF2       35 -- this row will be kept    
GHI3       65
JKL9       100
```

Ouput table:

```
Company    Total_Revenue
ABC        10
DEF2       35     --kept 
GHI3       65
JKL9       100
```

Comment: What output are you looking for? Your first query is not much like your second. Are you wanting to group by the first 3 characters of the name? How does SQL know that DEF1 and DEF2 are "duplicate" rows?

Comment: what is the logic to ignore DEF1 from output

Comment: I have already done the majority of my groupby statements etc, i am just looking to get rid of names that look like duplicates by name, this would not be for the entire dataset, but just on known issues- so basically error handling for DEF and then return the normal set that is already within the table

Comment: sounds like DEF1 and DEF2 are the same company. are they named the same in the real example?

Comment: yes sorry, they are the same company, but basically a different reporting subsidiary, they eventually roll up to the same name in the reporting chain- unfortunately, based on the parameters of this report and how the data was entered, i am having to correct this report around the requests of mgmt vs reporting the results of the actual search haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few ways to do what it seems like you are after:

Using a subquery to find max revenue for each comp:

```
SELECT Company, Total_Revenue
FROM myTable
  INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT Left(Company, 3) as leftcomp, 
        max(Total_Revenue) as maxTotalRevenue
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY Left(Company, 3) 
    ) mt
    ON Left(myTable.Company, 3) = mt.leftcomp
    AND myTable.Total_Revenue = mt.maxTotalRevenue;
```

Window function that is later filtered by Where:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT Company, 
      Total_Revenue,
      MAX(Total_Revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY Left(Company, 3)) as maxTotalRevenue
    FROM myTable
  ) mt
 WHERE Total_Revenue = maxTotalRevenue;
```

Correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM myTable mt1
 Where Total_Revenue =
   (
     SELECT max(total_revenue)
     FROM myTable
     WHERE Left(myTable.Company, 3) = Left(mt1.Company, 3)
   );
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76a5b/11)

Answer (score 0):

You seems want `row_number()` function :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Company, 3) ORDER BY Total_Revenue DESC) AS Seq
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE Seq =  1;
```

Comment: Don't think this is quite it. Will still end up with 2 rows for DEF1 and DEF2, where OP doesn't seem to want DEF1 and DEF2. It's not very clear.

Comment: I'm betting their dataset might not be able to rely on the static 3 constant.

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function `max`() and sub-query

```
    select * from Yourtable t1
 where t1.Total_Revenue in (

  select max(T.Total_Revenue ) as Total_Revenue from
   ( 
   select case when Company like'%DEF%' then 'DEF'
   else Company end as Company , 
    Total_Revenue from Yourtable
   ) as T
    group by T.Company
   )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e896c/5

```
    Company  Total_Revenue
     ABC      10
     DEF2     35
     GHI3     65
     JKL9     100
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want ?

```
select * from t
where
Company not in (
    select Company from t where Company like '%DEF%' order by Company desc offset 1 
)
```